# WinUI3: DatePicker control shows margin to left and right side

Tags: c#, user-interface, datepicker, winui-3

I am using the [DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) control of WinUI3.

Windows App SDK versions I tested with were 1.0.3 and 1.1.1.

I noticed that the `DatePicker` is sometimes displayed with something that seems to be a fixed margin to the left and the right side.
This causes this control to be aligned differently to other controls that I have in this view.

Here is a screenshot that shows the problem. In order to show the margin, I added some kind of element in the background, so you can see the margin of the `DatePicker` in dark grey color. I also added two red arrows pointing to the respective area.
(By the way, the screenshot was taking using "Dark Mode").

[image]

In my case the DatePicker is displayed in a column of a `Grid` and it should simply adapt to the width of the `Grid` column.

Currently I have this code:

```
        <DatePicker Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Date="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.MyDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

What I already tried is specifying a negative `Margin` for the `DatePicker` which had no effect. Also specifying a `Padding` of 0 had no effect.

Do you know a way to get rid of this margin? I would be nice to have a solution that does not require to completely rewrite the control template.

Thank you.

**Update**

I noticed that the problem seems to be related to the maximum width the `DatePicker` allows. It appears that it has a maximum width of a little less than 500 units. If you try "to force" it to expand beyond this width, the undesired Margins begin to appear (see second Screenshot below).

Here is a complete example to reproduce it:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>  <!-- Column for Label -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>    <!-- Margin -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"></ColumnDefinition>   <!-- Column for content -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Title row -->
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="200" >Column that has 500 Width</TextBlock>

    <!-- First row with a TextBox control -->
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Label for Textbox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,20,0"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="200" ></TextBox>

    <!-- Second row with a DatePicker control -->
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Label for DatePicker" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,20,0"></TextBlock>
    <DatePicker Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="200"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></DatePicker>

</Grid>
```

In the screenshot you can see that the `TextBox` control is able to expand to a width of 500, whereas the `DatePicker` is not.

[image]

Comment: Currently I am using Windows App SDK 1.1.1. I noticed that it seems to be related the maximum width the DatePicker allows. The DatePicker is inside a grid. I will update to question with a complete example to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `DatePickerThemeMaxWidth` resource that constraints the maximum width of the `Button` in the `DatePicker`. There is also a `DatePickerThemeMinWidth` resource.

You could either create a custom template for the existing control or create your own custom control and override the `OnApplyTemplate()` method:

```
public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    private Button _flyoutButton;

    public CustomDatePicker() => SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _flyoutButton = GetTemplateChild("FlyoutButton") as Button;
        if (_flyoutButton != null)
        {
            // Note: The default value that gets overridden here for the MaxWidth is 456
            _flyoutButton.MinWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
            _flyoutButton.MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
        }

    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_flyoutButton != null)
        {
            _flyoutButton.MinWidth = ActualWidth;
            _flyoutButton.MaxWidth = ActualWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<local:CustomDatePicker Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: Could I also just override the "DatePickerThemeMaxWidth" setting in a resource file like so: <x:Double x:Key="DatePickerThemeMaxWidth">2000</x:Double>? I tried this in the "MergedDictionaries" part of my app.xaml file, but it did not work.

Comment: No, this is not possible since the resource is referenced using the `StaticResource` markup extension in the template.

Comment: Thank for your time and your solution! When testing it, it proved to be effective. However I noticed two things: A) Specifying the "MaxWidth" to the new value was sufficient, I did not need to set the "MinWidth". B) Unfortunately this approach somehow removed the rounded corners that were displayed before when using the unmodified "DatePicker".